# ValueError: time data '2015-06-29-16:27:07.157+00:00I-----' does not match

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I think I'm missing something but I really tried all possible combinations for datetime format. This one was my latest try and it throws the same error :

```
datetime.strptime('2015-06-29-16:27:07.157+00:00I-----', "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S+%I-----")
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: What error do you get ? please show more code

Comment: You missed `00:00` and also you need `%Y` for year format and `%m` for month!

Comment: I thought **00:00** is part of the %I as it is variable

Comment: `%I` is the hour again; what you would need is a `%z` with a `-` separator between hours and minutes; and that doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your string format is not a valid date time you can just put `00:00` directly on `strptime` format :

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2015-06-29-16:27:07.157+00:00I-----', "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00I-----")
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 29, 16, 27, 7, 157000)
```

For more details have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the format `00:00` as a timezone format is not something `strptime` can work with: it requires something like `(+/-)0000`, without the colon. So the following does work:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2015-06-29-16:27:07.157+0000I-----', "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f%zI-----")
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 29, 16, 27, 7, 157000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

but you would need to remove the `:` in the timezone part.